# cannot load such file -- puma/capistrano (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, puma

I'm attempting to use the puma gem w/ Capistrano. When I do `cap deploy` however I get `cannot load such file -- puma/capistrano (LoadError)`. What am I doing wrong here?

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'puma', :git => "git://github.com/puma/puma.git"
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/puma/puma.git
  revision: 2280b68d987bfe17f00bb92c772b971a4f073ca6
  specs:
    puma (2.0.0.b1)
      rack (~> 1.2)
```

**deploy.rb**

```
require 'puma/capistrano'
```

**stacktrace**

```
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- puma/capistrano (LoadError)
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
    from ./config/deploy.rb:3:in `load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from Capfile:4:in `load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/cap:19:in `load'
    from /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find `require 'puma/capistrano'` with 2.0.0.b7

https://github.com/puma/puma#capistrano-deployment